# I can't figure out how to set up browserstack properly on travis CI

Tags: travis-ci, browserstack

I read and followed the instructions at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/browserstack/ to set up https://github.com/cellog/react-redux-saga-router and it doesn't work.  It claims there is no username, even though I clearly set up a username.  You can see the error message at https://travis-ci.org/cellog/react-redux-saga-router and the source for travis.yml at https://github.com/cellog/react-redux-saga-router/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing was the browserStack username and access key within karma.conf.  Once I added these, it worked perfectly.